# create a seq with an ifelse statement in r

Tags: r

I have a column in data frame that tracks changes in time.   I'm struggling to figure out how to write an ifelse statement to create a sequence so that when a number (change in time) is greater than 10, it will step up one.  For instance, to make a snippet, here is the input:

```
input <- c(1,1,1,2,5,2,4,9,11,1,1,15,2,1)
```

Here is the output I desire:

```
output <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
```

When there is a number over 10, the next number in the vector steps up to 2 and then 3.

I've tried doing something like using ifelse to create a flag like this:

```
ifelse(input>10,1,0)
```

But I can't seem to put it all together.    Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cumsum`

```
cumsum(c(TRUE,(input>10)[-length(input)]))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the comment.  I didn't notice it earlier.